# MySQL query to get value information from another table based on id with 3 different attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to query data with MySQL database.

I have 2 tables.

tbl_alarm

```
id | alarm | file
1  | Alarm1| Alarm1.mp3
2  | Alarm2| Alarm2.mp3
3  | Alarm3| Alarm3.mp3
4  | Alarm4| Alarm4.mp3
```

tbl_profile

```
alarmFront | alarmLeft | alarmRight
1          | 3         | 2
```

Now I need to get alarm file based on id in tbl_profile. So the view will be like this.

```
alarmFront | alarmLeft | alarmRight
Alarm1.mp3 | Alarm3.mp3| Alarm2.mp3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a313b7/2)

How can I do it on sql query code?

Comment: You can join tbl_alarm table thrice like https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8jxdDCekvrds1ydFR8NUPy/0

Comment: Hi @Prasanna, please put it on your answer. It's working very well